# How to control the speed of bullets?

Tags: python, pygame, motion

I have made a simple 2D game, but when the hero shoots, some of the bullets move faster then others, especially the bullets that come out from the hero's corners (the shape of hero is simple box).

Here is how I wrote the shooting code (I wrote that line just to make sure the bullets go into the right direction). I am using Python 3.5.2.

Run the code and keep shooting randomly everywhere, and you will see that some of them are faster.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (0,25)
pygame.init()
x=pygame.display.set_mode((1360,705))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
kx=[]
ky=[]
kx1=[]
ky1=[]
while True :
     x.fill((0,0,0))
     for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type==QUIT :
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                if event.type== pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                     xvx=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                     xa=(int(xvx[0]))
                     ya=(int(xvx[1]))
                     wox=(xa-680)
                     woy=(ya-352)
                     ox=wox/70
                     oy=woy/70
                     while True :
                         if xa >= 700 or xa <=660 or ya>=372 or ya<=332 :
                              xa=xa-ox
                              ya=ya-oy
                         else :
                              break
                     pygame.draw.line(x,(255,150,100),(xa,ya),(680,352))
                     kx.append(xa-1)
                     ky.append(ya-1)
                     kx1.append(680)
                     ky1.append(352)
     for i in range (len(kx)):
          wox=(kx[i]-kx1[i])
          woy=(ky[i]-ky1[i])
          ox=wox/20
          oy=woy/20
          kx[i]=kx[i]+ox
          ky[i]=ky[i]+oy
          kx1[i]=kx1[i]+ox
          ky1[i]=ky1[i]+oy
          pygame.draw.rect(x,(250,250,250),(kx[i],ky[i],2,2))
     pygame.display.update()
     clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Can you add some meaningful variable names please, as of now it's hard to understand what is happening

Comment: BTW: if you have `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event then you have mouse position in `event.pos` and you don't need `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`. Both give position as integer values so you don't have to use `int()` - `xa, ya = event.pos`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code appears to use the position of the mouse when you click it to determine the speed. A click further away results in a faster shot. But it sounds like you want the position of the mouse only to determine the direction of the shot, with all bullets getting the same speed.

This is a job for vector normalization!

You can turn the position vector you calculate by subtracting the click position from your character position into a unit vector by dividing it by its own length. Then you can multiply the unit vector by the desired speed.

Try something like this:

```
if event.type== pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
     xvx=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
     click_x = int(xvx[0]) - 680 # get relative position of the click
     click_y = int(xvx[1]) - 352
     distance = math.sqrt(click_x**2 + click_y**2)
     unit_x = click_x / distance            # make a unit vector
     unit_y = click_y / distance
     BULLET_SPEED = 20   # this constant could be defined elsewhere
     velocity_x = unit_x * BULLET_SPEED     # make the velocity vector
     velocity_y = unit_y * BULLET_SPEED
     pygame.draw.line(x, (255, 150, 100),
                      (680, 352), (680+velocity_x, 352+velocity_y))
     kx.append(680 + velocity_x)
     ky.append(352 + velocity_y)
     kx1.append(680)
     ky1.append(352)
```

I've used more  meaningful variable names, so hopefully the code is easier to understand than your original with its excessively terse names. You could shorten things a bit if you want by combining some of the sequential operations into one combined operation on one line (e.g. there's no need for the `unit_x` and `unit_y` variables to exist, you could go straight to `velocity_x` and `velocity_y` by multiplying in the speed at the same time you divide by `distance`).

Note that I've left the `kx`/`ky` and `kx1`/`ky1` lists as they were, but might make more sense to store the components of the velocity of the bullet in `kx1`/`ky1` instead of storing the former position (since you're subtracting the positions to get a velocity anyway).

You might also consider making a `Bullet` class to store the position and velocity of the bullet together in one object rather than having several parallel lists.

Comment: @OP pygame has [pygame.math.Vector2](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) which has methods `distance_to()`, and `normalize()` - so later you can write @Blckknght code in shorter way.

Answer (score 0):

@Blckknght descibed problem, I only show how to do it with [pygame.math.Vector2](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2)

BTW: instead of 4 lists `kx`, `ky`, `kx1`, `ky1` I use one `bullets` and keep all information as list `[position, speed]` where `position` and `speed` are `Vector2` so they are kept as float and values are rounded to integer only when pygame draw objects.

```
position += speed
```

or

```
position.x += speed.x
position.y += speed.y
```

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pygame
import os

# --- constants ---

WIDTH = 1360
HEIGHT = 705

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (250, 250, 250)

BULLET_SPEED = 5

# --- classes ---

#empty

# --- functions ---

#empty

# --- main ---

# - init -

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = '0, 25'

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# - objects -

bullets = []

# center of screen as Vector2
#center = pygame.math.Vector2(WIDTH//2, HEIGHT//2)
center = pygame.math.Vector2(screen.get_rect().center)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type== pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:

                # get vector from center to mouse position
                vector = event.pos - center
                # `center` is `Vector2` so `vector` will be `Vector2` too
                #print(type(vector))

                # normalize
                normal = vector.normalize()

                # create speed vector
                speed = normal * BULLET_SPEED

                # move object (first move 5 times bigger then next moves )
                pos = center + (speed * 5)

                #pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,150,100), (pos.x, pos.y), (center.x, center.y))
                pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,150,100), pos, center)

                # remeber position and speed as one object
                bullets.append( [pos, speed] )

    # - draws -

    for pos, speed in bullets:
        # move
        pos += speed

        # draw
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (pos.x, pos.y, 2, 2))

    pygame.display.update()

    # - speed -

    clock.tick(60)

# - end -
```

Comment: thank you so much this was very useful 
i am new in learning python and programming (started just few months ago)
so i didnt understand few things in your code do you have any thing i can read to understand your code more ? like anything to read and understand more of the gaming math ?

Comment: I don't have one place for all information. I learned all from many places and books for many years - I don't even remeber this places and books.

Comment: There is so many tutorials, video tutorials and books in internet. ie. see [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/), or maybe [GameDev.net](https://www.gamedev.net/)